# Print the index of an array next to the array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to print an array's element with it's index next to it. If the array element is even, it must display the element and its correlating index number, if the element is odd, it must display the element and "1".

For example:

Input: `int[] array = new int [25]`

Output: `0:0, 1:1, 2:2, 3:1, 4:4, 5:1, 6:6, 7:1` and so on

How would I do this?

Comment: Note: you're misusing "array" here. An array itself doesn't have an index, nor is the array even or odd. The array is *the whole thing*. You have array *elements*, which then have an index. As it is, I can't tell whether when you say "If the array is even" you mean "If the array index is even" or "If the array element is even" - because in the example you've given, they have the same result. Additionally, the example you've given is inaccurate because a new array is populated entirely with zeroes... please clarify your question.

Comment: show us your code and refer this to provide details in your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like, You can check if a number is `even then print the number and index` separated by a colon else print `number and 1 separated by a colon`, This can be achieved by using `for loop construct`.Would recommend you to follow proper guide/tutorial as you look like a beginner in java.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i : array) {
        if(i % 2 == 0)
            System.out.print(i+":"+counter);
        else
            System.out.print(i+":1");
        if(counter<array.length-1)
        System.out.print(", ");
        counter++;
    }
```

Comment: Why use the counter variable? Since it is always equal to `i` you can use `i` instead of the counter

Comment: @StephanHogenboom as I use for each loop construct , here variable I is nothing but the value inside the array, so it is not a counter, if used for loop then it would be possible.